# passing a variable into a json collection

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to call the following js method. I wish to pass in the variable siteid. I can alert this value. But it doesn't seem to work in the following context. ie if just add the id 1234 it works.

alert(siteid);

```
embedSWF ('flashcontent', '{"siteID":siteid,"siteType":"portal","mainSWF":"http:\/\/tv.xxx.net\/flash\/xxx1.swf","movieWidth":"426","movieHeight":"276","expressInstall":"http:\/\/tv.xxx.net\/expressInstall.swf"}');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to concatenate the value of `siteid` into your string: `'...' + siteid + '...'`

Depending on what you're building, you may want the string to have quotes around the value.

Comment: Do you also build your XML by using string concatenation?

Comment: No, but that's a separate issue.

Answer (score 2):

The most robust way to do this is to first make the object as a normal object and then serialize it:

```
var parms = {siteID: siteid, siteType: "portal", ...};
embedSWF('flashcontent', JSON.stringify(parms));
```

If you need to support outdated browsers that don't have the built-in JSON object, there are several [implementations](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js) available online.

Answer (score 0):

```
embedSWF ('flashcontent', '{"siteID":'+siteid+',"siteType":"portal","mainSWF":"http:\/\/tv.xxx.net\/flash\/xxx1.swf","movieWidth":"426","movieHeight":"276","expressInstall":"http:\/\/tv.xxx.net\/expressInstall.swf"}');
```

Answer (score 0):

You're passing a string:

```
 '{"siteID":siteid,"siteType":"portal","mainSWF":"http:\/\/tv.xxx.net\/flash\/xxx1.swf","movieWidth":"426","movieHeight":"276","expressInstall":"http:\/\/tv.xxx.net\/expressInstall.swf"}'
```

You probably mean to pass:

```
'{"siteID":' + siteid + ',"siteType":"portal","mainSWF":"http:\/\/tv.xxx.net\/flash\/xxx1.swf","movieWidth":"426","movieHeight":"276","expressInstall":"http:\/\/tv.xxx.net\/expressInstall.swf"}');
```

It seems a little weird to pass a JSON string, rather than the associative array itself. Either way, that's your problem, above.